# Expand clicked item to full width with Isotope

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am writing a testimonials page which has a number of small boxes in three columns with a snippet of text in them which when clicked will expand to full width and show the full testimonial. There is also a fixed info box in the grid using Isotope's stamp feature.

Here is a jsFiddle of what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/HjdAn/4/

My JS:

```
var $container = $('.testimonials').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  stamp: '.stamp',
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: '.column-sizer',
    gutter: '.gutter-sizer'
  }
});

$container.on( 'click', '.item:not(.info-box)', function() {
    $container.find('.item.read-more').not(this).removeClass('read-more');

    $(this).toggleClass('read-more');

    $container.isotope('layout');
});
```

When you click on a white box, it expands and shows the full text which is great - but it doesn't re-calculate the layout properly. For example, if you click on the third white box, it should move down a line as it does, but then two of the elements that were below it should move up to fill in the gap left by the expanded box.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

I do realise, that you have probably sorted that one or another since 2014, but perhaps this will help someone else in similar situation.
What you've got is basically working to the specs of Isotope. Do I understand right you'd like testimonials excerpt boxes to fill in the empty gaps? If so, and if you don't need the filtering that is provided by Isotope, you might consider using [Packery](https://packery.metafizzy.co/) from the same authors as Isotope. This has the option to fit the layout better by shuffling around the boxes. Mind you, you still end up with some gaps when expanding testimonials around the stamp. Here's my clone of your fiddle – http://jsfiddle.net/planxdesign/o9yjopkk/2/

The JS code itself is very similar to yours:

```js
var $container = $('.testimonials').packery({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  stamp: '.stamp',
  columnWidth: '.column-sizer',
  gutter: '.gutter-sizer'
});

$container.on( 'click', '.item:not(.info-box)', function(e) {
  $container.find('.item.read-more').not(this).removeClass('read-more');
  $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('read-more');
  $container.packery('layout');
});
```